# mysql how to group records with time in series

Tags: mysql

Say I have the following records in TableA:

```
UserID, Date, GroupNo, StartTime, EndTime
4, 2015-08-03, 1, 2015-08-03 08:00:00, 2015-08-03 09:00:00 
4, 2015-08-03, 1, 2015-08-03 09:00:00, 2015-08-03 10:00:00 
4, 2015-08-03, 1, 2015-08-03 13:00:00, 2015-08-03 14:00:00 
4, 2015-08-03, 1, 2015-08-03 14:00:00, 2015-08-03 15:00:00 
4, 2015-08-03, 1, 2015-08-03 15:00:00, 2015-08-03 16:00:00 
4, 2015-08-03, 2, 2015-08-03 17:00:00, 2015-08-03 18:00:00
```

Is there a way I can use a query to group my records into 3 rows whereby all the linked time(EndTime)=time(StartTime) will be group together?

The end result of the query will be:

```
UserID, Date, GroupNo, StartTime, EndTime
4, 2015-08-03, 1, 08:00:00, 10:00:00 
4, 2015-08-03, 1, 13:00:00, 16:00:00 
4, 2015-08-03, 2, 17:00:00, 18:00:00
```

I think the query should look something like this:

```
select UserID, Date, GroupNo, min(time(StartTime)) as StartTime,   
       max(time(EndTime)) as EndTime
from TableA
group by "??"
```

But I am not sure how to group it by...

Is it do-able?

Thank you very much.

In case the data is not already in sequence, or when there are other dates involved: I find this modified query to be working: (for others who may need to know in future)

select userid, min(date) as date, groupno, min(time(starttime)), max(time(endtime))
from (select a.*,
             (@grp := if(@ugt = concat_ws('-', userid, date, groupno, time(starttime)),
                         if(@ugt := concat_ws('-', userid, date, groupno, time(endtime)), @grp, @grp),
                         if(@ugt := concat_ws('-', userid, date, groupno, time(endtime)), @grp+1, @grp+1)
                        )
             ) grp
      from (select * from TableA where userid=4 order by date, Time(starttime)) a cross join
           (select @grp := 0, @ugt := NULL) params
      order by userid, date, groupno, time(starttime) 
     ) a where userid=4
group by userid, groupno, grp
order by date, time(starttime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a pain in MySQL, but possible.  You need to keep track of the times to identify when a new group starts.  Variables is probably the simplest way:

```
select userid, min(date) as date, groupno, min(starttime), max(endtime)
from (select a.*,
             (@grp := if(@ugt = concat_ws('-', userid, groupno, starttime),
                         if(@ugt := concat_ws('-', userid, groupno, endtime), @grp, @grp),
                         if(@ugt := concat_ws('-', userid, groupno, endtime), @grp+1, @grp+1)
                        )
             ) grp
      from tableA a cross join
           (select @grp := 0, @ugt := NULL) params
      order by userid, groupno, starttime
     ) a
group by userid, groupno, grp;
```

The idea is to sort the data by the `userid`, `groupno`, and `starttime` (perhaps `date` should be included as well, it is hard to tell from the question).

Then assign the variable `@grp`.  This value does not change when the keys are the same.  The value is incremented when the keys do change.  There is a bit of trickery because the `endtime` on the previous row needs to be compared to the `starttime` on the current row.

Finally, `@grp` is used for the aggregation.

Comment: Thank you very much. It does according to what was requested. Yes, the date will be needed. I will try to work on that. Thanks.